# Google Maps markerClusterer + InfoBubble - selectively display or hide based on cluster true or false

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer, infobubble

I have markerCluster working fine with InfoBubbles (a utility for gmaps v3).

It looks like this:

[image: My map with marker clusterer]

Last little improvement here is to make the infoBubbles disappear IF the markers have been clustered.  You can see the (3) in the image and you see some phantom infoBubbles floating nearby but no markers underneath them.

The code says:

```
infoBubble[i] = new InfoBubble({
content: '<div id="msg" class="map-text" style="font-size:13px">'+res[i].job.start_time+" -"+res[i].job.end_time+'</div>',                                                  hideCloseButton: true,
padding: 2,
disableAutoPan: true,
});
infoBubble[i].open(map,marker);
```

My idea is to wrap the last line, infoBubble[i], into an if block that says something to the effect of "if marker, open" where it's marker or cluster.

I just can't figure out the right syntax to describe this condition.  Any ideas?

*UPDATE*

The marker clusterer is exceedingly simple:

```
 var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
            minimumClusterSize: 3,
        });
```

I think the answer is to say something like "if infoBubble grid > 60, infoBubble.open"k

60 being the default grid size of the marker clusterer, within this boundary is when the heat marker will appear and the marker itself disappears.  So it stands to reason that I can apply the same logic to the infoBubbles themselves "faking" their disappearance.

But then I need a trigger when I zoom in and out to re-write the map again (I think I do that today...)

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I pasted my code in the question...  The only relevant part is the infoBubble part.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  What does the _rest_ of your code look like. I think the configuration of the MarkerClusterer might be somewhat relevant.